# What is "Rook Box" and its use?

Tags: endgame, draw, rooks

When I once watched a chess game on television, one player use a trick named "Rook Box" to draw a game. I didn't understand its move and so, I want to know what is "Rook Box" in chess.

I know it's a good trick for making a game draw.

Comment: I have never heard of this.

Comment: Can you provide the position from that game? I have never heard for such a term ( although I am not a native English speaker ) ?

Comment: This is not a common term.

Comment: It could be referring to this specific puzzle - http://www.chess.com/forum/view/daily-puzzles/11232007---rook-box

Comment: I think this is a useful pattern to learn.

Answer (score 6):

Well, it is as simple as encasing a rook in a virtual box. We'll take the example and see it.

```
 [Date "????.??.??"]
 [Result "*"]
 [FEN "1k5r/1P3K2/8/2p2p2/7p/4P3/8/3R4 w - - 0 1"]

1.e4 fxe4 2.Kg7 Rh5 3.Kg6 Re5 4.Kf6 Re8 5.Kf7 Rh8 6.Kg7
```

We see that the rook is trapped inside a 4x4 box. Losing the rook means losing the position, and the only way not to lose it is to stay inside the box, and be constantly pushed by the king. If White doesn't do so, he is in serious trouble.

Comment: A page with this position was the only relevant search result for "rook box chess" so I guess that if anything is the answer, this is.

Comment: It should be noted that this is just one specific example and there is no such general concept as a "rook box".

Comment: I would also add why it is important that black captures the pawn back. Nothing is mentioned here or in the webpage where it comes from. Without that note, I find this example almost useless.